# webpack watch cache between instances

Tags: javascript, caching, webpack, build, instance

Anyone have an example of webpack's cache option shared between instances? In the [Webpack's docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cache) it sais:

> You can pass an object to enable it and let webpack use the passed object as cache. This way you can share the cache object between multiple compiler calls. 
>   Note: Don’t share the cache between calls with different options.

But it is not clear about the implementation. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in an empty object. If you pass in the same object to another instance, they will share the same cache.

```
// Webpack.config.js
var cacheObj = {};

module.exports = {
    cache: cacheObj
}
```